# Creating a workspace for an AWS EMR Studio results in Javascript error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-emr-studio

When I try to create a new workspace for an AWS EMR Studio in the AWS Console, I get a blank page and a Javascript error in the console ("Failed to execute 'mark' on 'Performance': Symbol(react.element) could not be cloned")

[image]

This is clearly a bug in EMR Studio. What can I do as a workaround?